# Tag user in image post

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, tags

I have a canvas app which can let users upload pictures to friend's timeline. Doing a photo upload works ok, but i'm trying to tag the user's name in the picture's name. I don't know which part of my code isn't right. The picture is uploading, put the tag is not there. What am i doing wrong?

```
         FB.api(
            '100003980685577/photos',
            'post',
            {
                url: 'url to photo',
                name: 'Tiberiu Maxim sent you a kiss via kissapp',
                name_tags: {
                    "0": [
                        {
                            "id": 1033568851,
                            "name": "Tiberiu Maxim",
                            "type": "user",
                            "offset": 0,
                            "length": 13
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            function(result) {
                console.log(result);
            }
        );
```

The explanation of my code: user 1033568851(Tiberiu Maxim) is logged in and granted permissions. He is sending a kiss photo to user with id 100003980685577 and Tiberiu Maxim should be tagged in the name of the photo

Answer (score 0):

Looks like i can't find the answer to my question. Instead of posting a photo to friend's timeline, i've created an open graph action, which includes a mention tag. All i had to to is post the action including the 'message' parameter with some text value, in which you tag persons like this:

```
This is a message for @[user_id]!
```

where user_id is obviously a user id.

!Don't forget to check the tags option when you submit your action for approval

FB documentation is [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/mention_tagging/)