# How can I use the name_tags field of the Photo object?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, tags

Uploading a photo, and setting the name (caption) of that photo is no problem, I am trying to tag a name I mention in the caption. According to the documentation, the way to do that is with the name_tags field.

The field is listed in the [api-reference](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/), but I can't find the correct way to use it, and there is no example either.

I could find [one other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12526077/tag-user-in-image-post) about this here, but it was never answered (he just gave up and used something else).

Does anyone know if the name_tags field is actually there to be used through the api, and if yes, how?

Comment: name_tags is available when _reading_ from the API – but you want to _create_ a photo. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/#tags

Comment: Are you saying you want to tag the photo ( https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/#tags ) or you want to mention names? (mention tagging) https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/mention_tagging/ I think mention tagging would be associated with a post about the photo, but not included on the title of the photo itself. So you could create a post about a photo and attach the image to the post, and then mention people in that

Comment: Sorry for responding this late, but our client stopped this project alltogether, so I had no reason to pursue this further. I did some investigating, and came to the conclusion that mention tagging is the only viable solution in this case, like TommyBs said. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try to using `message_tags` field.